# MongoDB cursors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-cursor

I just wanted to verify something about cursors.
Please let me know if the following statements are correct:

1. The cursor is created on the `mongoDB database server`. So, it takes up the RAM/memory on the database server.
2. After firing a find query, I need to wait until the scan is complete to find the query result.
3. Once the entire scan is complete, the cursor is created and then I can iterate over the results instead of fetching the whole result set `over the wire` at once.
4. Setting the batch size to 1k does not mean that, if my result has `10k` documents, the find will keep returning `1k` documents as soon as it finds those many and then proceed to find another 1k and so on.

In conclusion, if I set my batch size for cursor to 1k and I know that my result set is having 100k documents, and if the `find/aggregate` query cursor takes 5 seconds to do that search and create the cursor from the collection of 300k documents, I **have to wait** for 5 seconds until I can start using iterating on that cursor.

There is no way that if the first `1k/100k` documents have been searched in 1 second of the total 5 seconds, those 1k will be returned and I can start processing them. There is **no way I can start streaming** the results until the entire result set is ready.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Cursors *do* stream.

You should be getting the first batch of results as soon as the server has it, not when the entire result set is obtained. The point of cursors is to never actually hold  the result set in memory on the server if the result set is available via other means (e.g. by sequentially iterating a collection).

> The cursor is created on the mongoDB database server. So, it takes up the RAM/memory on the database server.

Yes, there are some resources associated with cursors.

> After firing a find query, I need to wait until the scan is complete to find the query result.

What is "the scan" referring to?

You need to wait for the server to identify the first batch size of documents. If you are doing, for example, a query that requires sorting the entire collection, then the collection must be completely iterated before you get the first document. If you are doing a query that doesn't require sorting it may return the first batch before all matching the documents are visited by the server.

> Once the entire scan is complete, the cursor is created and then I can iterate over the results instead of fetching the whole result set over the wire at once.

Correct on iteration, see above on "the entire scan".

> Setting the batch size to 1k does not mean that, if my result has 10k documents, the find will keep returning 1k documents as soon as it finds those many and then proceed to find another 1k and so on.

It does, if the query can be fulfilled in this way.

> In conclusion, if I set my batch size for cursor to 1k and I know that my result set is having 100k documents, and if the find/aggregate query cursor takes 5 seconds to do that search and create the cursor from the collection of 300k documents, I have to wait for 5 seconds until I can start using iterating on that cursor.

No, unless your aggregation pipeline does something like an unindexed sort as the last stage.

> There is no way that if the first 1k/100k documents have been searched in 1 second of the total 5 seconds, those 1k will be returned and I can start processing them.

No, this is possible if query is satisfiable via index scans or collection scans and does not require sorts.